# Script doesn't work when event is changed from "mouseover" to "click"

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

The following script doesn't work when I change the event to "click" instead of "mouseover". Any idea why?
What I mean by doesn't work is, that I cant POST any JSON data to the JSON storage service.

```
<script>
const button = document.getElementById("search-image")
const s = document.getElementById("s")
function SendData(){

   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   var url = "https://krat.es/xxxxx";
   xhr.open("POST", url, true);
   xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

   xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {

       if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {

           var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

       }
   };

   var data = JSON.stringify({"Text": s.value});
   console.log(data)
   xhr.send(data);
}
button.addEventListener("mouseover",SendData)
</script>
```

Update: HTML code

```
<form _lpchecked="1" action="/search" class="search-form" id="searchform" method="get">
<fieldset>
<input id="s" name="q" onfocus="if(this.value=='Search')this.value='';" onwebkitspeechchange="transcribe(this.value)" type="text" value="Search" x-webkit-speech="">
<button class="sbutton" id="search-image" style="border:0; vertical-align: top;background: transparent;"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: If you put a `console.log` inside the SendData function does it log? Also are you sure the button is clickable and some element isn't overlayed on top.

Comment: What are you clicking? Does it trigger navigation and thus cancel any current HTTP requests?

Comment: Could you show your HTML code as well? Where `button` is defined. And do you get any error messages? Or nothing inside `SendData` gets executed on changing the event?

Comment: @CasperKuethe yes, it does log when I put console.log(data) inside the function.

Comment: @Quentin I'm clicking a search button. When the button is clicked, a new page is opend. I think the HTTP requests it being canceld, but I dont know how to fix it. What should I google?

Comment: The event should be `mouseenter` and not `mouseover` to prevent multiple requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button is inside a form. So when you click the form button, it will be sent and will not allow your JavaScript code to run.

So change the button code this way


html :

```
/* type="button" */
    <button type="button" class="sbutton" id="search-image" style="border:0; vertical-align: top;background: transparent;"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
```

js :

```
button.addEventListener("click",SendData)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace mouseover with click and you need to type the text on search area and enter you will be able to get the response

```
button.addEventListener("click",SendData)
```

[please refer below link for full code](https://codepen.io/mitulT/pen/QWmLvNb?editors=1111)